# AJAX checkbox in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, checkbox

I want to make a checkbox in every data cell in the table. When I click the checkbox, it should save the change to the database change via AJAX.

My view code:

```
foreach($dataProperty as $property)
{
    echo form_checkbox('prop[]','$property->property_id','TRUE'). "On/Off";
}
```

My AJAX:

```
$("#prop[]").clicked(function(){
    var prop_id = $("#prop[]").val();
    $.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        url     : "<?php echo base_url('property/update_property'); ?>",
        data    : "prop_id=" + prop_id
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**property Controller**

```
public function update_property() {
    $prop_id = $_POST['prop_id'];
    //call the model class function to update db
}
```